# A function that contains multiple of two numbers

Tags: functions

Is there any way to create one mathematical formula $f(x)$ which contains both multiple of two number. For example if $f(x)$ contains both multiple of $3$ and $7$ should generate this sequence.
$3,6,7,9,12,14,15,18,21...$

The function should not have condition.

```
f(x)= {| A if condition1 }
      {| B if condition2 }
```

It should be just a plain function like $f(x) = x^2 + 4.$
It's combination of $3x$ and $7x$ but how to do it, that is if it's even possible.

EDIT1:

Can this function be used for any given

a,b ∈ N and if is it consistent so it can be used for X ∈ N where X is a set of numbers e.g. {2,3,5,7}

EDIT2:

I don't want to ask another question as this is still related

If you can find a union of two functions as shown on the answers is also possible to do subtractions

say f(x) = 3x

and g(x) = 7x

I want to do f(x) - g(x) but not 3x - 7x but from the result

lets say the function is h(x) of such

h(1) -> h(8) = {1,3,6,9,12,15,18,24}

Comment: I do not believe that is possible @Dev_anon101. There appears to be no generalization, and it would be difficult to define one even with conditions. However, a multivariable function with conditions will do the trick.

Comment: @AksharGandhi what do u mean by multi variable could you give an example?
Are you talking about var a = f(3x) = [3,6,9,12,...]
var b = f(7x) = [7,14,21,...]
var c = a + b ??

Comment: ignore it, it was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing there won't be a simple, explicit formula but with the help of [Sloane's OEIS](https://oeis.org/A176409), this appears to work:
$$\begin{align}f(n) = \; & 21\left\lfloor \frac{n}{9} \right\rfloor + 2 \left( n \,\mbox{mod}\, 9\right) + \left\lfloor \left( n \,\mbox{mod}\, 9-1\right)\sqrt{2} \right\rfloor \\[8pt] & -2\left\lfloor \frac{n \,\mbox{mod}\, 9-1}{\sqrt{2}} \right\rfloor+1-\left\lfloor \frac{1}{8} (n-1) \,\mbox{mod}\, 9\right\rfloor\end{align}$$
Here, $\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor$ indicates the [floor-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) of $x$.

You can test the formula with e.g. [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=21*floor(n%2F9)%2B2*(n%20mod%209)%2Bfloor(((n%20mod%209)-1)*sqrt(2))-2*floor(((n%20mod%209)-1)%2Fsqrt(2))%2B1-floor(((n-1)%20mod%209)%2F8)%20for%20n%3D%7B1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12%7D).

Comment: The formula works for 3 and 7 but how does it differ for any two number and does it work only for 2 multiples or n multiples, e.g. multiples of x,y,z...?

Comment: @Dev_anon101 This indeed only works for 3 and 7 and I don't know how [Gary Detlefs (OEIS)](https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Gary_Detlefs) arrived at this formula.

Comment: @Dev_anon101 Looking at the formula I think he's using the fact that the differences are periodic. (note he starts with n/9 as 9 is period) The sum of the differences is 21 so he essentially jumps by the period length and than deals with the additions. Since the periodicity exists for all pairs of numbers I'm pretty sure this can be done for an arbitrary pair.

Comment: @Dev_anon101 If you don't mind the floors and mods you can do this by using the fact that $a\lfloor ((n - a-1)\mod 9)/8\rfloor$ is equal to $a$ if $n=a$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @DRF this only works for on multiple at a time it would be same as doing n % a if 0 it's a multiple otherwise it's not
I tried using the formula to do same for 2,5 by doing 
10*floor(n/9)+2*(n mod 9)+floor(((n mod 9)-1)*sqrt(2))-2*floor(((n mod 9)-1)/sqrt(2))+1-floor(((n-1) mod 9)/8) for n={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}
but does not generate the same sequence.
Is 3,7 only numbers people looked at?

Comment: @Dev_anon101 Of course the same formula won't work for different numbers. But the modification is easy. Since you know the length of the period $p+q-1$ (as per the note on OEIS) you know the period for 2 and 5 is 6 and just have to pop in the 6 different offsets. There was no reason to really look at any others since this solves the problem for all possible pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be a little more specific on what you mean by "function". For example, we could use a step function and modular arithmetic to achieve your result by doing

$f(x) = 3 \lfloor (x_2 + 1) \rfloor + 7 \lfloor (x_2) \rfloor$

Where $x_2$ is the value of $x$, mod 2, and the $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the floor function (round down). You may note however, that this is entirely equivalent to your piece-wise definition. (Note, for those with a complex background, DRF gives a more elegant version of this function in the comments).

But what it sounds like you want is a *continuous function* with that property. The only way I can think of to do this off the top of my head (and there are likely many by discipline) is to use an infinite series work around e.g.

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$

Where $f_n(x)$ is the [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) with appropriate weight.

But both of these are just formalized workarounds of your piece-wise version that you are trying to avoid. In some sense, any function can be defined piece-wise (and thus every function is piece-wise).

So without more information on what you mean by "function" it is difficult to answer this further.

As a final footnote, you can get more interesting functions for any *finite* number of multiples of your factors by using [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation).

Comment: -1 First of all your $f(x)$ isn't what the OP wants since it doesn't list the multiples in increasing order. $f(0)=3, f(1)=7, f(2)=6$. That function you could get with a "niceish" definition namely $f(x)=3(1+(-1)^x)/2+7(1+(-1)^{x+1})/2$ It's still just a work around but it managed to get the result as an elementary function (no mods or floors/ceils). Second of all there will be infinitely(continuum) many distinct functions that achieve what the OP wants not a single one since he only prescribes the value of the function on the positive integers.

Comment: Well crap, you are right. I entirely misread his question. I thought he asked for a function that gave *only* the multiples and in alternating order.
This is what I get for looking at stack exchange while I'm waking up in the morning, my bad!

Comment: My proposed function was aimed for someone without a complex background. Yours is much better as long as one can interpret $(-1)^x$ correctly. I just find the floor function a bit more digestible in general, hence why I went that route.

Comment: I suppose you are right that it's easier to read. If you would fix the claim that any two functions that satisfy the OP's criteria are equal I would be quite happy to upvote. Though the way it's phrased I suppose it might be right. Any function is equivalent to **its own** piece-wise form by definition but that doesn't seem to say anything and there are certainly infinitely many different (even $C_\infty$) functions that satisfy the OP's criteria.

Comment: Edited to reflect the actual question that was asked by removing the comment on piece-wise functions (and directing those with complex background to the better function in the comment by DRF).

Comment: Vote changed to +1. Feel free to just edit the function in so people don't need to read the comments. We might aswell delete them now.

Answer (score 1):

If by plain function you mean a polynomial than the answer is no.

The reason is that it doesn't grow fast enough. It is easy to see that $7x$ is an upper bound on the integers for $f(x)$. Actually $7x$ grows quite a bit faster.

Now there are two possibilities. Either from some point on $f(x)$ is increasing in which case it would have to be a polynomial of at most degree $1$ since it increases slower than a polynomial of degree one. It is easy to see that it can't be a polynomial of degree one since the first three values are not collinear.

Or there is no point from which point onwards $f(x)$ is increasing which means for every $x$ there is a $y>x$ such that $f(y)<f(x)$ which means that the first derivative has infinitely many $0$'s so $f(x)$ again can't be a polynomial.

Edit: I wonder if you could get an elementary function that does this though. My tendency is to think that the answer is yes since the OEIS mentions the differences are periodic.

Edit 2:

Just to point out how to get a boring yet general result using the information from OEIS.

If you have any pair of primes $p$, $q$ you can use the information that $f(n+p+q-1)=f(n)+p*q$ to get an easy formula for a given $n$. Find the first $p+q-1$ values and call them $a_i$ and define $f(x)=p*q\lfloor \frac{x}{p+q-1}\rfloor + a_0\lfloor \frac{((x-1)\mod (p+q-1))}{p+q-2}\rfloor +a_1\lfloor \frac{((x)\mod (p+q-1))}{p+q-2}\rfloor +a_2\lfloor \frac{((x+1)\mod (p+q-1))}{p+q-2}\rfloor +\cdots +a_{p+q-2}\lfloor \frac{((x+p+q-2)\mod (p+q-1))}{p+q-2}\rfloor$

Edit 3:

In response to the new part of the question regarding a set of numbers. Assuming the numbers are prime the periodicity stays except it doesn't seem obvious what the length of the period is. I would guess it will be something like the euler totient function of the product of the primes, but don't see it straight away. Once you know what the length of the period is you use the exact same approach except that $p+q-1$ becomes the length of the period and $pq$ becomes $p_1p_2p_3p_4\cdots p_k$ for $k$ primes.

Comment: What is a1, a2, a3 ... is it ai so (p*q)?

Comment: $a_0$ through $a_{p+q-2}$ are the first $p+q-1$ elements of the series. I.e. those are $f(0)$, $f(1)$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(n)=21 \left \lfloor \frac{n}{9} \right \rfloor + \sum_{k=0}^{n \mod 9} \left (\left\lfloor \frac{312321330}{10^{k}}\right\rfloor \mod 10 \right )$$

Why ? Well, first of all the gaps between values repeat with a period of 9. In fact, when we increase n by 9 we want f(n) to increase by 21 i.e. $f(x+9) = f(x)+21$ so we start with
$$f(n)=21 \left \lfloor \frac{n}{9} \right \rfloor + g(n)$$

and we want g(n) to repeat the sequence 0,3,6,7,9,12,14,15,18, which suggests that g should be a function of n mod 9. The term
$$\left\lfloor \frac{312321330}{10^{k}}\right\rfloor \mod 10$$

selects the (k+1)st digit of 312321330 from the right, and these values are just the term-by-term differences in the sequence we want to produce. So summing these values from 0 to n mod 9 creates the repeating sequence 0,3,6,7.9,12,14,15,18 and then back to 0.

(Inspired by [Tupper's self-referential formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupper%27s_self-referential_formula))

Comment: This is nice but you're abusing notation a tiny bit since you are really defining the sequence piece wise by putting the $n \mod 9$ on top of the sum. You need some other trick to unroll it.

Comment: @DRF if you prefer, the upper limit on the sum could be $n-9 \left \lfloor \frac{n}{9} \right \rfloor$ instead

Comment: The problem isn't the formula $n\mod 9$ is fine by me. The problem is that using using a sum with a variable upper limit. If you roll it out you get a piece wise defined functions.

Comment: I can get rid of the sum completely and replace it with $10^{2n}\left(\frac{30607091214151800}{10^{18}-1} \right)\mod 100$

Comment: ... my bad ... that should be $\left \lfloor 
 10^{2n} \left ( \frac{30607091214151800}{10^{18}-1} \right) \right \rfloor \mod 100$

Comment: Very nice.:) That gets rid of the sum well.